# Get Url From Another Opened Window With Different Origin

Tags: javascript

I want ask something:

I need to open different site from main window using

```
window.open(http://different-site.com/new_window_pt1,'New Window')
```

And I want to make that opened window closed if the url on that window contains token params:

```
http://different-site.com/new_window_pt2?token=sometokenthingshere
```

then send that params to main window.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you do

```
var win1 = window.open;
```

you have the handle to that window already and you can read its URL by

```
var win1URL = win1.location.href;
```

and if you are looking for only parameter values after `?` then

```
var win1URLSearch = win1.location.search;
```

now you can search this value to see if it contains token (didn't get from your question about this search part). If this condition is true then

```
win1.close();
```

Comment: I think it works but I got: Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost.com:3000" from accessing a frame with origin "https://www.instagram.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match. lol anyway thanks for it!